# Why does x-ray films look better when illuminated with light?

Tags: x-rays

Today I got an x ray of myself and it seems that it was much easier to distinguish between bones in the x ray when the films were illuminated with light from either side from either side. What is the physics explanation of why this phenomena happens?

Comment: I always figured it was because they didn't want to blast more x-rays than necessary through your body in order to more strongly expose the film to produce more contrast. It's like a low-light photo.